# If buying a distillery, what would you focus on?

Tags: spirits, distribution, distilleries, distillation

As I receive many offers of Latin American spirits and do not have any experience in marketing those (high quality) products I think to buy into an existing distillery with skilled personnel, to use their distribution channels and add further spirits to the existing range of products.

But besides sales and distribution channels, what should I pay attention to most?

Answer (score 3):

Having owned and run a winery for 15 years (as well as making the wine, it was a small operation), you should concentrate on Sales, Marketing and Distribution about 90% of your effort. You could bottle paint thinner and with the right sales team and marketing you could make tons of money. I've seen it in the wine industry many times. People will say "if you make a quality product, people will buy it" is not true. Branding, marketing and sales make or break almost any product. Look at the Pet Rock for gods sake!

Comment: I hoped to receive a different answer, but it is as I expected. Probably a good explanation why some spirits generate headache and others don't. They say that spirits reduce life time, however "Queen Mum" had her daily Gin and died in old age with more than 100 years. She definitely had no reason to consume a cheap Gin.

Comment: I know your comment on selling paint thinner was a joke, but shouldn’t safety of the product be at least of moderate importance?

Comment: In most countries Alcohol is highly regulated and tested for quality. (We are talking about spirits not beer and wine). However there are places in the world were there is little regulation and people put all kinds of crap into booze to make more money.